# how to add rinkeby test network to metamask

Tags: web3js, metamask, smart-contract-wallets

Hy
I'm a beginner, I installed metamask but I can't get the Rinkeby test network.(I followed the instructions but in the end the Rinkeby test network doesn't appear.
Please can you help me

Comment: Rinkeby is deprecated and this question is being "protected" as there's not much more to add to it.

Answer (score 3):

The Rinkeby and Ropsten testnets have been deprecated as of October 5th, 2022.

Answer (score 1):

Though the Rinkeby Testnet is deprecated now, but Metamask automatically provides Rinkeby in its networks. You need to click on `Show/Hide test networks` in the networks section.